# Weber Genesis caught on fire

Tags: safety, gas, natural-gas, fire-hazard, fire-extinguisher

I was grilling chicken and some of the fat dripped into the cabinet and the gas line caught on fire burning through the sheathing and making a hole in the line itself, leading to a major fire inside the cabinet. Fortunately, I caught it in time.

Was my grill faulty? How does one prevent something like this from happening?

[image]

Comment: No drip pan? My Weber has one

Comment: I've never seen a weber grill with a line INSIDE and UNDER the grill. The tanks run on the side. If you've got this running to a main line then I can see this. Either way, as noted above, the grill has a drip pan, The manufacturers manual that came with it prescribe all of the cleaning and safety tasks you should be doing. Seeing leaves in there and the grease that is unburned on the bottom implies you arent keeping it clean underneat and the tray emptied replaced. If you do those things, fire is very unlikely.

Comment: Have you Checked the owners manual or installation manual to verify the N. G. conversion was done properly?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because operation of major appliances is off topic here. This question doesn't involve maintenance or repair (to original spec). See the [help].

Answer (score 1):

Same happened to me. It's a bad weber genesis design. The rubber propane hose attaches upward very close to right end of drip pan so even small grease  fires can reach the rubber line. A small metal divider is needed.